# Reload UiTableView After Data Has Been Retrieved From Database - Swift

Tags: ios, database, uitableview, asynchronous

How do I reload a UiTableView only after the data has been loaded from the database. I have a datasource class that contains the function to load in all the data, and stores the data after it has been loaded into an array.

When I access the data using the Tableview though it displays nothing because the tableview loads before the database has returned its data. The only way to load the data is for me to have a button that manually reloads the tableview.

How do I cause the tableview to automatically reload once the array in the datasource object has been populated from the database?

Comment: Just call ```tableView.reloadData()``` just what Smartcat said, after you access the data.

Comment: are you using core data to store your data in database ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being a new programmer it took me a while to learn this was even possible, but I just realized completion blocks are the way to go. It will carry out some specified code only after your function has finished fetching from the database. In this case, I can update the tableview AFTER I've retrieved the data from the database. Here's an example.

Function definition:

```
func getDataFromDatabase(someInput: Any, completion: @escaping(String?) -> Void) {
    let retrievedData: String = databaseCallFunction()        
    // 'Get data from database' code goes here
    // In this example, the data received will be of type 'String?'
    // Once you've got your data from the database, which in this case is a string
    // Call your completion block as follows
    completion(retrievedData)
}
```

How to call the function:

```
getDataFromDatabase(someInput: "Example", completion: { (data) in 
    // Do something with the 'data' which in this example is a string from the database
    // Then the tableview can be updated
    let tableView.title = data
    tableView.reloadTableView
})
```

The code in the completion block will happen AFTER the database call has completed.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just call tableView.reloadData() once you've populated your data?  It'll repopulate the entire table (well technically it'll only re-create whatever cells are visible).

The point is that your tableView:cellForRowAt: method should have the ability to access your data so as to fill in each table cell appropriately based on that data.  Anytime your data changes, just call tableView's reloadData() again.  It's efficient in that only the visible cells will be created, and the rest will be created whenever they are about to become visible, if ever.

Also, tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: should similarly be looking at your data to judge how many rows shall exist.  It too will be called again during each call to reloadData().

Your data should always be prepared to be interrogated by the tableView delegate methods, even when it doesn't contain anything yet.  When there's no data, your tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: would decide there should be 0 rows.

Comment: I can paginate data from the database and cause the tableview to reload once I start scrolling down the screen. But my problem is on the initial loading of the first set of data. How do I call `tableview.reloaddata()` only after the data has loaded in from the database. What datasource method would I use to call it, and how would I call it only once the database returns its data?

Comment: To answer this I'd need to see your code. In general, it sounds like you need to separate the database access from the array of data that represents the data the tableView is to display. So basically have a property in your view controller that holds the array the tableView is to reference. It's always referenceable, even if it's an empty array. Now the code that references the database, such as to fetch a filtered set of data from it, should update that array. Wherever that code lives, it needs to trigger a call to tableView.reloadData() (send a UINotification message, or call a closure, etc)